# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference | FLASH BUILD/STARLING FRMWRK

Tags: flash

The language i am coding in is Actionscript and i am still kind of new to it.The following error was obtained after running debug mode in Flash Build (using starling framework)

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:117]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:106]
    at screens::Welcome/drawScreen()[C:\Users\Kyle\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\StarlingProject\src\screens\Welcome.as:44]
    at screens::Welcome/onAddedToStage()[C:\Users\Kyle\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\StarlingProject\src\screens\Welcome.as:30]
    at starling.events::EventDispatcher/invokeEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\events\EventDispatcher.as:146]
    at starling.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\events\EventDispatcher.as:117]
    at starling.display::DisplayObject/dispatchEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObject.as:395]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/broadcastEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:379]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/broadcastEventWith()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:389]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:135]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:106]
    at Game/onAddedToStage()[C:\Users\Kyle\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\StarlingProject\src\Game.as:22]
    at starling.events::EventDispatcher/invokeEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\events\EventDispatcher.as:146]
    at starling.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\events\EventDispatcher.as:117]
    at starling.display::DisplayObject/dispatchEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObject.as:395]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/broadcastEvent()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:379]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/broadcastEventWith()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:389]
    at starling.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\display\DisplayObjectContainer.as:135]
    at starling.core::Starling/initializeRoot()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\core\Starling.as:439]
    at starling.core::Starling/initialize()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\core\Starling.as:410]
    at starling.core::Starling/onContextCreated()[C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Gamua-Starling-Framework-def24cc\starling\src\starling\core\Starling.as:649]
[SWF] C:\Users\Kyle\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\StarlingProject\bin-debug\StarlingProject.swf - 731,536 bytes after decompression
```

I will list and show all the code for each class.

Game.as class -

```
package
{
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;
    import screens.Welcome;

    public class Game extends Sprite
    {
        private var screenWelcome:Welcome;

        public function Game()
        {
            super();
            this.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("starling framework initialized!");

            screenWelcome = new Welcome();
            this.addChild(screenWelcome);
            screenWelcome.initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

Assets.as class -

```
package
{
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import starling.textures.Texture;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;

    public class Assets
    {
        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/bgWelcome.jpg")]
        public static const BgWelcome:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_hero.png")]
        public static const WelcomeHero:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_title.png")]
        public static const WelcomeTitle:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_playButton.png")]
        public static const WelcomePlayBtn:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_aboutButton.png")]
        public static const WelcomeAboutBtn:Class;

        private static var gameTextures:Dictionary =  new Dictionary()

        public static function getTexture(name:String):Texture
        {
            if (gameTextures[name] == undefined)
            {
                var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
                gameTextures[name] = Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            return gameTextures[name];
        }
    }
}
```

Welcome.as class

```
package screens
{
    import starling.display.Button;
    import starling.display.Image;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;

    public class Welcome extends Sprite
    {
        private var bg:Image;
        private var title:Image;
        private var hero:Image;

        private var playBtn:Button;
        private var aboutBtn:Button;

        public function Welcome()
        {
            super();
            this.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(event:starling.events.Event):void

        {
            trace("welcome screen initialized!");

            drawScreen();
        }

        private function drawScreen():void
        {
            bg= new Image(Assets.getTexture("BgWelcome"));
            this.addChild(bg);

            title= new Image(Assets.getTexture("WelcomeTitle"));
            title.x = 440;
            title.y = 20;
            this.addChild(title);

            bg= new Image(Assets.getTexture("WelcomeHero"));
            this.addChild(hero);
            hero.x = -hero.width;
            hero.y = 100;

            playBtn = new Button(Assets.getTexture("WelcomePlayBtn"));
            this.addChild(playBtn);
            playBtn.x = 500;
            playBtn.y = 260;
            this.addChild(playBtn);

            aboutBtn = new Button(Assets.getTexture("WelcomeAboutBtn"));
            aboutBtn.x = 410;
            aboutBtn.y = 380;
            this.addChild(playBtn);
        }

        public function initialize():void
        {
            this.visible = true;

            hero.x = -hero.width;
            hero.y = 100;

        }
    }
}
```

And last but not least 'StarlingProject.as'

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import starling.core.Starling;  

        [SWF(frameRate="60", width="800". baxkroundColour="0x3333333")]
    public class StarlingProject extends Sprite
    {

        private var myStarling:Starling;

        public function StarlingProject()

        {
            myStarling = new Starling(Game, stage);
            myStarling.antiAliasing = 1;
            myStarling.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Please try and get back to me. :)

Thanks, 
DT.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of the Asset class has no such property as BgWelcome, WelcomeHero, etc

This would be an instance property:

```
public const BgWelcome:Class;
```

This is a class property:

```
public static const BgWelcome:Class;
```

The static keyword makes it a class property, not an instance property.

When you do:

```
new Assets[name]();
```

You create an Asset instance and try to access a property that doesn't exist in that scope. If you were to declare your variable like this it would work:

```
public const BgWelcome:Class;
```